# Php within language file? Codegintier

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, internationalization

I have my language files all set up, and everything is great when it comes to plain text. But in that plain text, I would like a link.

Here is my controller

```
function home()
{
    $data['masthead'] = '/includes/masthead';
    $data['content'] = '/includes/content_3_col_box';
    $this->lang->load('en', 'english');
    $data['text1'] = $this->lang->line('home1');
    $data['text2'] = $this->lang->line('home2');
    $data['text3'] = $this->lang->line('home3');
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

This is my view which serves the dynamic language

```
<div class="content grid_24">
<div class="grid_7 firstboxthree alpha column">
<?php 
echo $text1;
?>
</div>
<div class="grid_7 midboxthree column">
<?php 
echo $text2;
?>
</div>
<div class="grid_7 lastboxthree omega column">
<?php 
echo $text3;
?>
</div>
```

This is my language file line in question

```
$lang['home1'] = "Introducing the most comprehensive protection plan in the industry <br /><br /> . echo anchor('controller/function', 'Text')";
```

Html markup seems to work great, but how can I pass off a codeigniter link in the form of echo anchor('controller/function', 'Text')? Right now, it's just passed off as plaintext instead of php/html codeigniter generated link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$lang['home1'] = "Introducing the most comprehensive protection plan in the industry <br /><br />" . anchor('controller/function', 'Text');
```

Comment: Fantastic! that's what I was missing

Comment: You might also want to have a look at this library: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/i18n_Multi-language_Library_Helper